# Retrieve data via JSON and put in a form

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

I´ve tried retrive some info from mysql for put it in a form,and update the info.
I use ajax call in the same page,I call ajax passing the id and php return all info.

```
if(isset($_POST["retriveForm"])) {
    $data_json =array();
    $id  = $_POST['retriveForm'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE Id = $id";
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($db->consulta($sql)) {
       $data_json  = array('item1' => $row['item1'],'item2' => $row['item2']) ;
    }
    $data_json['item_array'] = call_a_function_return_array();//this works
    echo json_encode($data_json);
}
```

ajax call shows like this

```
 $(document.body).on('click', '.edit' ,function(){
                var id = $(this).data('id');
                $.ajax({
                  type: "POST",
                  url: "is_the_same_page.php",
                  data: {retriveForm : id},
                  success: function(response) {
                     $('#myForm').find('input').eq(1).val(response.item1);
                  }
                });
 });
```

When put .val(response.item1) get anything,but if I put response the input take all values

```
$('#myForm').find('input').eq(1).val(response);
```

shows

```
{"item1":"item1","item2":"item2","item_array":["item_in_array1","item_in_array2"]}
```

I also tried

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `$.ajax()` `dataType` options to `"json"`

> `"json"`: Evaluates the response as JSON and returns a JavaScript
>   object.

```
 $(document.body).on("click", ".edit", function() {
   var id = $(this).data("id");
   $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "is_the_same_page.php",
     dataType: "json", // set `dataType` to `"json"`
     data: {
       retriveForm: id
     },
     success: function(response) {
       $("#myForm").find("input").eq(1).val(response.item1);
     }
   });
 });
```

Comment: it works when pass anything to php ,but if a try to pass data to php ,the php  get anything.That could be that I put all in the same page(jquery and php) and the trigger for php is `  if(isset($_POST["retriveForm"])) `

Comment: @Ini Not certain what you mean? Initially appeared that text was returned from server as `response`, not a `javascript` object _"`$('#myForm').find('input').eq(1).val(response);`
shows

`{"item1":"item1","item2":"item2","item_array":["item_in_array1","item_in_array2"]}`"_. Setting `dataType` to `"json"` should set `response` to a `javascript` object

Comment: now speak the data from JQuery to php (initially I wrong why I didn´t use the var,I did a workaround for test my ajax call) .Now if i put $id  = $_POST['retriveForm']  $id takes any value (I wonder if it could be for I send a json instead html .

Comment: @Ini Are you currently receiving expected result at `php` and `javascript` ? What is purpose of two similar variables `$data_json` and `$datos_json` at `php`?

Comment: data_json and datos_json are the same array (it was a error and I just edited). my problem is I don´t know the way to send id that I take from jquery `var id = $(this).data("id")` and pass it to php I think the problem is `if(isset($_POST["retriveForm"]))` it seems never comes the condition ,so never get response

Comment: Does `$(this)` element at `click` handler have `.data("id")` set? Are any errors logged at `javascript` or `php`?

Comment: the problem is in php,in javascript all work,I tested `var id` and take the value correctly .

Comment: At Question response was described as initially being returned as text. No value is currently being returned now?

Comment: no,at the moment don´t get any response why I don´t know how enter inside the php `if` ,I think when send `retriveForm` from jquery with of the type `json`   don´t get any in `$id=$_POST['retriveForm']`

Comment: What does `call_a_function_return_array()` return?

Comment: call_a_function_return_array() works,but if I delete that line still any response get

Comment: Which version returned `{"item1":"item1","item2":"item2","item_array":["item_in_array1","item_in_array2"]}` as `response`?

Comment: Thanks for you help,I posted the problem correctly(I [hope](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38407528/pass-value-from-jquery-to-php-and-return-a-json))

Comment: Have Answers at linked Question provided solution?