# Pass value from JQUERY to PHP ,and return a JSON

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

When call php from jquery via ajax ,have any response .I changed the `dataType`and put `json`instead `html`.I´m thinking the issue is that,for the ajax call never trigger the php code,it seems `$_POST['retriveForm']` never carries a value.

PHP:

```
if(isset($_POST["retriveForm"])) {
    $data_json =array();
    $id  = $_POST['retriveForm'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE Id = $id";
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($db->consulta($sql)) {
            $data_json  = array('item1' => $row['item1'],'item2' => $row['item2']) ;
    }
    $data_json['item_array'] = call_a_function_return_array();//this works
    echo json_encode($data_json);
}
```

and jQuery :

```
$(document.body).on('click', '.edit', function() {
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "is_the_same_page.php",
        data: {
            retriveForm: id
        },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(response) {
            $('#myForm').find('input').eq(1).val(response.item1);
        }
    });
});
```

Code is all in the same page if that may be important.

Comment: can you use `!empty($_POST["retriveForm"])`

Comment: What does `var_dump($_POST)` show?

Comment: @guradio it´s the same ,the problem `$_POST["retriveForm"]` is always empty.

Comment: Check the response in the Network tab of the browser console. Maybe you're not sending back valid JSON.

Comment: does your var id have value? maybe you are sending empty value to retriveForm?

Answer (score 0):

Since the AJAX code is in the same script, make sure you don't output any of the normal HTML in this case. Your PHP code should be at the very beginning of the script, before any HTML is output. And you should exit the script after echoing the JSON. Otherwise your JSON will be mixed together with HTML, and jQuery won't be able to parse the response.

Also, you're not correctly adding to `$data_json` in your loop. You're overwriting the variable each time instead of pushing onto it.

```
<?php
// code here to set up database connection
if(isset($_POST["retriveForm"])) {
    $data_json =array();
    $id  = $_POST['retriveForm'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE Id = $id";
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($db->consulta($sql)) {
        $data_json[]  = array('item1' => $row['item1'],'item2' => $row['item2']) ;
    }
    $data_json['item_array'] = call_a_function_return_array();//this works
    echo json_encode($data_json);
    exit();
}
?>
<html>
<head>
...
```

Then in the `success` function, you'll need to index the elements of `response`, since it's an array, not a single object.